# GIT: Multiple Origins for master branch

Tags: git, branch, remote-access

I am trying to have two source controls for my project in Visual Studio: Gitlab and VSTS. I was successfully able to add multiple pushurls for origin, but the problem is that VSTS is outside of the corporation, thus it goes through proxy, and Gitlab is in our premises. I was looking for a solution to make VS push to two URLs, but using proxy for only one. The only solution I found was to create two remotes, set in global config default proxy and for the 2nd remote set proxy to "".

My .gitconfig file:

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy = https://xxxxxxxxxxx:8080
[rerere]
    enabled = 1
[core]
    editor = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NotepadPP.611\\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
[branch]
    rebase = preserve
[rebase]
    autoSquash = 1
[remote "origin"]
    proxy =
```

My project .git/config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = https://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin2"]
    url = https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_git/xxx
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin2/*
    pushurl = https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_git/xxx
```

is there a way to set multiple remotes for 1 branch?

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
```

Or any other workaround?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A branch can have only one upstream, and the `remote` is half the setting of the upstream,<sup>1</sup> so no, you can't have two remotes for one branch.

If you weren't stuck with VS, the obvious workaround would be to run something other than `git push`, e.g., to have your own alias or command that does two `git push`es.  I have no idea if VS can be convinced to run something other than `git push` though.

---

<sup>1</sup>The two halves are `branch.branch.remote` and `branch.branch.merge`.